# Wordpress sidebar not displaying

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I've created a Wordpress website using the Divi theme for a client. The site has been working fine but recently I've run into a problem: The sidebar module (Divi) is not displaying [See here an example](https://planthopeisrael.com/the-miracle-of-passover-in-amsterdam-2019/)

I've used the default 'sidebar' widget here. It contains search, recent posts, categories and a menu but it's not displaying.

I've tried a number of things:

1. Disable plugins and reload to see if any of those are causing a conflict.
2. Tried different widgets but none of them seem to be working.
3. looked for faulty CSS

I also checked the standard wordpress pages (not using the divi theme) and here the sidebar also has disappeared. For example on the search page ([see here](https://planthopeisrael.com/?s=jennifer)).
When I look at the CSS it looks like the sidebar is still there, it's just not displaying.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am clueless where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sidebar is hidden in your Inline css
Go to your style.css in your theme files and add this line in any place, this must work.

```
.et_pb_widget {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved the problem. Any idea how this was caused? Would it be due to updating wordpress?

Comment: You are welcome, probably no, maybe some bugs in the theme's module caused that..

Comment: Ok no worries, thanks anyway, this has been immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[You can see on the image that your sidebar widgets are display none on css.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyhVh.jpg)

You need to remove the css or use different css class for sidebar widgets.